# How does water respond in 0g?

Tags: microgravity, water, rotation

I'm imagining a small orb magnetically suspended inside a sphere of any paryicular size floating in 0g.

What would happen if you rotated the orb at a high/varied velocity?

And what if you change the position of the ball within the sphere (for example close to the surface of any point)?

Also does changing the axis of rotation give different results?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid your question is a bit too vague to be answerable. For example, what exactly does "magnetically suspended" mean?

Answer (score 3):

Rotating a sphere of water in space would cause it to deform into more of a lens shape but before long the acceleration caused by the spin would overcome surface tension and the outer parts of the sphere would disintegrate into a number of blobs of water which would immediately form themselves into a lot of smaller spheres all drifting away from the central sphere. It would not matter which axis you used.

Changing the position of the ball inside the sphere of water would create a lot of disturbance in the spinning water which would probably swiftly overcome surface tension causing the sphere to deform and then disintegrate into a lot of small blobs of water which would then form into spheres of themelves. Equates to a big watery mess either way.

Comment: There's a video of [a wet tennis ball being spun up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAs8XNqwB7g) which sort of shows what would happen, given it's not in 0g, but the idea is the same. Major difference is those blobs would spherical and continue in the direction they were accelerated in (relative to you) instead of falling to Earth.